# How can I populate a git-repository with the content of a PLESK-site

Tags: git, plesk

I have a already working homepage/site, which I would like to update from now on using git on a local repository.

So far I have started with "Using a local repository on your workstation" in Plesk (Obsidian).

But a pull request on the local machine said that there is an empty repository.
A git add on the server did also not show any effects.

My questions:

What Do I need to do to populate the server-side-repository with my running system, so that I can pull it down to my development workstation.

EDITED: 2021-02-07

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that this is not an available functionality today, I have found a solution here

https://talk.plesk.com/threads/commit-changes-made-on-the-server-with-git-extension-for-plesk-onyx.342362/post-863667

Thanks to Alex Movergan.